# hbase shell run jruby scripts with xml file as input

Tags: hbase, jruby

I wrote a JRuby script taking an XML file as input.

My JRuby script's name is `myruby.rb`, and my XML document is named `myxml.xml`

If I wanted to use `hbase shell` to run my JRuby script, what command should I run?

I wrote `cat myxml.xml | hbase shell myruby.rb`

It does not seem right. Can you please give me some advice?

Comment: What seems not right? Does the command give an error? Does it show no progress?

Comment: I had to do something similar just now, and got it to work exactly with that format, `cat myxml.xml | hbase shell myruby.rb`